# How to read a custom binary file made with Adobe air into Unity 3D & C#

Tags: file, compression

I have a custom data file from a project that was authored in actionscript some years ago by another developer.  I am porting parts of the project over to Unity 3D.  I don't have any documentation for the original project (I hope to speak to the original developers at some point but I cannot wait for that).

The file is a special bitmap that represents the positions of objects on a grid.  The custom file is created using an editor created in Adobe air.  I believe (not knowing any better) that the source code I have for the file decoder is the same source from the editor.  I don't have the editor source code.

Where I am getting into trouble is the binary file. From what I can tell at the moment, the file is a compressed byte array on the Adobe air side of things.  I don't believe I can just load the compressed file with Unity3D as a resource object. I would like to decompress the file and use it as an asset in Unity.

I am trying to figure how to decompress the binary file.  I have tried viewing the file contents in a hex editor to establish what the compression format is with no joy; I have not done anything specifically like this before .  I have tried to use gzip and a few other apps to decompress the file.

Form what I have read in the action script documentation that the default compression should be zlib.

Here is some edited code from the original project for decoding the bitmap:

import flash.utils.ByteArray;

public function decode(byteArray:ByteArray):Boolean
    {
        var i:uint;
        var j:uint;

        if(colourMap!=null)
        {
            colourMap.dispose();
            depthMap.dispose();
        }

        byteArray.uncompress();
        byteArray.position=0;

        var fileVersion:String=byteArray.readUTFBytes(FILE_VERSION.length);

        if(fileVersion==FILE_VERSION)
        {
            numWidth=byteArray.readUnsignedInt();
            numHeight=byteArray.readUnsignedInt();

            if(numWidth==0)
            {
                numWidth=30;
                trace("WARNING FOR SOME REASON WIDTH WAS 0 FROM FILE");
            }

            if(numHeight==0)
            {
                numHeight=30;
                trace("WARNING FOR SOME REASON HEIGHT WAS 0 FROM FILE");
            }

Here is a hex dump of the initial part of the binary data file:

78 da ec bd 55 cf 6c 5d 76 a5 79 7c 53 2a ff 8c

Comment: I realize now I was getting things mixed up.  A compressed data stream is not the same as a compressed archive.  The data file does not have any header information to indicate what the contents are as it just a stream of bytes.  I will report back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to de-compress the data file using an answer from here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22834/how-to-uncompress-zlib-data-in-unix

The printf is creating a gzip header to coax gzip into decompressing the byte stream.

```
printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" |cat - somedata.raw |gzip -dc
```

Where "somedata.raw" is the compressed byte stream.

To save the uncompressed data to a new file I changed the above to:

```
printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" |cat - somedata.raw |gzip -dc > uncompressed_data.raw
```

I viewed a hex dump of the head of the new file & it was what I expecting.

```
0000000 42 37 31 2d 30 2e 32 00 00 00 31 00 00 00 21 01
```

The first 3 characters are B71 which what I am expecting it relates to the a version number in the data file.

Heh heh, it has been years since I had to think about ASCII code.